# What is the different bewteen the minimum attenation in butterworth and Chebyshev filter?

Tags: low-pass, active-filter, frequency-response

I have desgined n of a low-pass butterworth whose specification  are  fc=1khz , fs=2khz, Amax = 1 db and Amin=40 db. I found that I need to make sure the n gives me larger Amin which = 40db. So I found n = 8 which has A(ws)=42.2db

In other side, when I designed a Chebyshev  for same specification I should find n that gives me A(ws) larger than 20 db why not 40db ? I found n = 3 which have A(ws) = 22dB
I am confused why I do not use n= 5 which have A(ws) = 45.31 db.

I found in some books this sentance "The Chebyshev  reponse rolls off at an ultimate rate of -20db/dec, just ike a Butterworth reponse of the same order" I think this is related to what is above. but I do not understand it. Could you please clarify it.

Comment: Chebychev Filters have steeper skirts due to higher Q poles that are balanced to create equiripple, whereas Butterworth are critically balanced to have no ripple in the passband.

Answer (score 3):

The two filters both roll off at n*20dB/dec, but what this means is asymptotically. You'll start to see the roll-off for f>>fstop. The Butterworth has a shallower roll-off before fstop and the Chebyshev has a steeper roll-off before fstop. That's why to attain the Astop you need a lower order filter with a Chebyshev design.

Look at the two plots below, from your specs, and compare the slope at f>>fstop (f=2..3kHz) -both at n*20dB/dec- But their respective slopes around f= 1..1.2kHz are different from their asymptotic slope.

You have made a good observation that has plagued many who look closely!

Calculations and images from https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/

[image] [image]

Compare a Butterworth-5 with a Chebyschev-3, they both have Astop = -20dB. But the response is not exactely (or mathematically) the same, and practically speaking which one you choose depends on how much ripple you can tolerate in the passband (0..1KHz) and how much attenuation you want around the cutoff.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you P2000 for clarification. I am still confused why in "Design with operational amplifiers and analog integrated circuits by Sergio France" chapter 4 in problem 4.2. They desgin Chebyshev at 3rd order to have Amin=20 db and they say it have same specs. with butterworth  that have above specs. ( Amin = 40db )
I got confused. Is there any rules than say that butterworth with Amin=40 db and Chebyshev Amin=20db have same repsonse ?

Comment: @Caro, I updated my answer in response to your comment

Comment: @P2000 Maybe OP will see better with [overlapped plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BNAL.png)?